# Extracting only one specified word from list of lists

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the following list of lists:

```
my_list=[['12,5', 'users'],
 ['12,5', 'users'],
 ['1,35', 'giga'],
 ['1,35', 'giga'],
 ['old', '(11,46', 'users'],
 ['(11,46', 'users'],
 ['contact', '2.926.685', 'accounts'],
 ['2.926.685', 'accounts', 'new,'],
 ['2.926', 'accounts']]
```

I am trying to create separate lists, one for each keyword:

```
keywords=['users', 'giga', 'accounts']
```

to see if there are differences in numbers. 
Since there can be more than one word in the list, e.g. in ['2.926.685', 'accounts', 'new,'], I would need to consider only the word included in the list keywords.

The expected output would be:

for `users`:

`(12,5 , 12,5 , 11,46 , 11,46)` (I need to not exclude the duplicates, as I am interested in their frequency)

for `giga`:

```
 (1,35 , 1,35)
```

for `accounts`:

```
 (2.926.68 , 2.926.68  2.926)
```

My difficulties are in extracting only the specific words included in `keywords` from `my_list`. After doing this, I should create as many empty lists as the number of words to extract.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over each list in `my_list`, checking for a value which matches a word in `keywords` (converting `keywords` to a set for efficiency), and if you find one, storing the numeric value into a dictionary (using a `defaultdict` for ease of use):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

my_list=[['12,5', 'users'],
 ['12,5', 'users'],
 ['1,35', 'giga'],
 ['1,35', 'giga'],
 ['old', '11,46', 'users'],
 ['11,46', 'users'],
 ['contact', '2.926.685', 'accounts'],
 ['2.926.685', 'accounts', 'new,'],
 ['2.926', 'accounts']]

keywords=set(['users', 'giga', 'accounts'])

result = defaultdict(list)

for l in my_list:
    k = None
    for v in l:
        if v in keywords:
            k = v
        if re.match(r'[0-9,.]+$', v):
            num = v
    if k is not None:
        result[k].append(num)

print({ k : v for k, v in result.items() })
```

Output:

```
{
 'users': ['12,5', '12,5', '11,46', '11,46'], 
 'giga': ['1,35', '1,35'], 
 'accounts': ['2.926.685', '2.926.685', '2.926']
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Nick. May I ask you how I can split the value and name, for example for users, in order to plot values frequency? In general I use a variable name and plot its values

Comment: @LucaDiMauro you can access `result['users']` to get just the values for `users`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!