# NameError when I try to append values

Tags: python

Could you please tell me why it does not find `num` in the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

result = defaultdict(list)

for l in my_list:
    k = None
    for v in l:
        if v in keywords:
            k = v
        if re.match(r'[0-9,.]+$', v):
            num = v
    if k is not None:
        result[k].append(num)
```

Error:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-84-31a1ed6e427e> in <module>
>      12             num = v
>      13     if k is not None:
> ---> 14         result[k].append(num)
>      15 
> 
> NameError: name 'num' is not defined
```

I cannot understand this error.

Comment: `num` variable is not initalized in your code

Comment: I am following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62461513/extracting-only-one-specified-word-from-list-of-lists . It has been working until today

Comment: Depends on the data this works, Ideally `num` never gets initalized until `if` condition pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the `num = v` is not always executed, it is run only when the if condition is `True`. First initialize `num` with a zero value, it will solve the error.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

result = defaultdict(list)
num = 0
for l in my_list:
    k = None
    for v in l:
        if v in keywords:
            k = v
        if re.match(r'[0-9,.]+$', v):
            num = v
    if k is not None:
        result[k].append(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable only gets created if your statment is true:

```
if re.match(r'[0-9,.]+$', v):
        num = v
```

If the statement is not true, the variable will not be created, which seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

result = defaultdict(list)

for l in my_list:
    k = None
    for v in l:
        if v in keywords:
            k = v
        if re.match(r'[0-9,.]+$', v): # Here is an if statement, and num only gets defined if the condition meets it
            num = v
    if k is not None:
        result[k].append(num)
```

If that `if` statement I commented on never meets, `num` never gets defined.

Answer (score 0):

I have placed comments in the bellow code. the "if condition" never got true hence the variable `num` never initialized.

```
     if re.match(r'[0-9,.]+$', v): # this if condition never got true
         num = v     # the initialization never executed
```

also it would be a good idea to check "re.match()" [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).\

Why the 'if condition' never got true, is because in your code you never included the '$' inside the character class.

```
if re.match(r'[0-9,.]+$', v): # the $ should be inside [0-9,.,$]
                num = v
```

['$' is usually a metacharacter, but inside a character class it’s stripped of its special nature](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).
I tried with my own string.

```
import re
String = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.,$"

if re.match(r"[0-9,.,$]", String):# $ should be inside character class
    print("matched") # this print statement executes output is `matched`
else:
    print("not matched")
```

The output of my code prints `matched`